# Keyboard shortcuts don't work in Selenium (Python, Firefox) [NOT JUST NEW TABS]

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm just trying to open a new tab, but it never happens. I don't receive any error messages either. I've tried the following methods.

1. `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')`
2. `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't').perform()`
3. `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

I've also tried adding "`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()`" in front of each to force Selenium to focus on the window. I would greatly appreciate help with this.

Thank you.

P.S. This applies for ALL Keyboard shortcuts. I just used Ctrl+T as an example.